# What are the hyperbolic rotation matrices in 3 and 4 dimensions?

Tags: matrices, hyperbolic-geometry

So the hyperbola-preserving transformation in 2 dimensional space is given by the matrix 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(\phi) & \sinh(\phi) \\
\sinh(\phi) & \cosh(\phi) \end{pmatrix}

I'm wondering what such a matrix would be in 3 dimensional space (so that it preserves 2 dimensional hyperboloids) and 4 dimensional space (so that it preserves 3 dimensional hyperboloids). Sources or derivations would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How about the Lorentz transformation for four dimensional space?

Comment: I am more wondering what your given matrix would do to a vector, say $<1,2>$

Comment: Transform it to <cosh(a)+2sinh(a), sinh(a)+2cosh(a)>

Comment: I'm not sure this should really be tagged hyperbolic-geometry, since you don't seem to use a hyperbolic metric anywhere. You are just talking about geometry involving a hyperbola. One exception would be a Beltrami-Klein model with this hyperbola as the fundamental conic. There your matrix would describe a translation along the line at infinity. Another exception would be if you wanted to consider the 3d analogon as the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane. But I don't see how either of these possible interpretations would be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

In a way, your transformation matrix is a variation of a common 2d rotation matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\\sin\phi&\cos\phi\end{pmatrix}\;.$$

Where the above preserves the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$, yours preserves the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$. The unit circle here corresponds to the unit sphere in 3d. There are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) to describe 3d rotations, but one very common one is to [describe them as a product of rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) around the coordinate axes. You can do the same for your hyperboloid as well.

For example, the one-sheeted hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ has rotational symmetry around the $z$ axis. So you'd have these three “rotation” matrices:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh\beta & 0 & \sinh\beta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sinh\beta & 0 & \cosh\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cosh\gamma & \sinh\gamma \\
0 & \sinh\gamma & \cosh\gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Each of them preserves the hyperboloid, so a product of them will preserve it as well. The two-sheeted hyperboloid $z^2-y^2-x^2=1$ is preserved by the above matrices, too. If you want $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$ instead, you have to change coordinates, so that the rotation around $x$ becomes a regular rotation while the other two use hyperbolic functions.

I don't know whether it would make sense to translate any of the other rotation formalisms (like axis-angle or quaternions) into something preserving a hyperboloid. Probably things would become too complicated to make this useful.

In four dimensions, you can try the same approach. You have $\binom42=6$ coordinate planes, and for each of them you can give a possible rotation matrix. If the signs of the coordinates in the equation of your hyperboloid are the same, you use a regular rotation, otherwise you use hyperbolic functions. So for example if you have $x^2+y^2+z^2-w^2=1$ then any matrix modifying the $w$ coordinate would use hyperbolic functions, while those that just involve two of $x,y,z$ are regular rotations using circular trigonometric functions.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful but I wanted to point out that the matrix I wrote down preserves the general hyperbola x^2-y^2=a^2 and the 2D rotation matrix that we all know and love preserves a circle of any given radius

Comment: @AnonYmous: You're right, scaling doesn't change these things. You essentially have something that keeps $x^2-y^2$ fixed. This is the reason why its 3d variant works for both the one-sheeted and the two-sheeted hyperboloid: one way to formulate them is by having the right hand side as $1$ for one and as $-1$ for the other equation, using the same left hand side. Remember that if this answered your question, you can accept the answer, and once you have 15 rep you can upvote answers you consider helpful. Also remember that placing `$` around formulas will typeset them as TeX, even in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Such generalizations occur when you introduce the *multisection of the $\exp()$-function*. If you remember, that $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ have powerseries from **each second term** of the powerseries for $\exp(x)$ then you can define $3$ functions by the the powerseries using only **each third term**. From this a matrix-formalism with $3 \times 3$ matrices occur which allow generalizations of the hyperbolic rotations to higher "orders".

I've made a small remark for me about this with some examples, see [here on my webspace](http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/ExpMultiSection.pdf)

I've found some more background in

- Brian David Sittinger, "Exponential Sums and the Multisection Formula", 27 January 2010 ;  *Slides (?)*
- Abraham Ungar , Generalized Hyperbolic Functions , 1982, AMM

Answer (score -2):

You can always transform any formula for spheric rotation into a formula for hyperbolic rotation by using the mathematical identities:
$$\cos x=\cosh ix$$
$$i\sin x=\sinh ix$$
$$\cosh x=\cos ix$$
$$\sinh x=-i\sin ix$$

Comment: On the other hand, I would not compose 3D rotations with matrices, but use 4D quaternions instead, which is the only safe way to perform a general 3D rotation. 3D space has holes (the vector product of collinear vectors is zero; --> gimbal lock), which is not the case with 4D space (which is tight). Hence always compose a 3D rotation by two 4D rotations: p' = (q)(p)(q*).

Comment: Herein q is a unit quaternion (cos(a/2), i(x sin(a/2)), j(y sin(a/2)), k(z sin(a/2))), and q* is its conjugate with negative imaginary parts. (x,y,z) is a unit vector in 3D space, indicating the axis of rotation, and a is the rotation angle around this axis. i,j,k are the imaginary axes, with i2=j2=k2=ijk=-1.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. If you take (x,y,z)->(ix,iy,iz) you would get complex rotation matrices even though we're working over a real vector space.

Comment: As far as your comments on quaternions go: I'm not sure what you mean by "vector product." If you mean wedge product, the wedge of any two collinear vectors in any number of dimensions is zero. If you mean geometric product, the geometric product of any two collinear vectors is scalar. It's also worth pointing out that unit quaternions can be surjectively mapped to "safe" rotation matrices. I believe the way differential geometers phrase the problem of gimbal locking is by saying that Euler angles form an atlas of SO(3) with a singularity, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Stepping back a bit, however, I don't see how quaternions are relevant because we're talking about hyperbolic rotations. So really you should be talking about the Clifford algebra of 2+1 dimensional Minkowski space

Comment: To answer to the Eben Cowley's comments:

Comment: A "vector product" in general sense is meant to be any product of two vectors, regardless on how it is defined.

Comment: The relevance of quaternions in physics is given by their roots in Leonhard Euler's algebraic 4-squares identity. This identity defines a vector product, even without the need to previously define quaternions; in this sense, quaternions are an "ex post facta" construction.

Comment: The algebraic identities given above allow to pass from spheric to hyperbolic space, at the price of having to deal with complex, quaternion, or octonion quantities. I admit that such is only possible in spaces of dimensions 2, 4 or 8 (rotational groups SO(2), SO(4), and SO(8)), because physical rotations are only possible in these spaces, if one is interested to avoid internal contradictions. A. Hurwitz's theorem is the decisive criterion for the existence of physical rotation